# How can I change the storage location of a contact in Android?

Tags: contacts, 9.0-pie, samsung-galaxy-s-9

How can I change the storage location of a contact in Android?

I don't see any option when editing a contact:

[image]

I use a Samsung Galaxy S9 with Android 9.

Comment: Do you mean SIM card?

Comment: @beeshyams storage location for contacts can be SIM card, Google account, Samsung account, etc.

Comment: For Google, Samsung or any cloud account, you need to sign in and enable sync-you don't "change" the location. For SIM card, if the OEM didn't provide an option, you could use a third party app

Comment: @beeshyams thanks, assuming I'm assigned in, which app allows to change the location of a given contact?

Comment: Once you are signed in and synced say with Samsung, you can either enable or disable sync, not change the location.. For transfer to SIM cards there are many apps available (search for SIM contacts) picked one at random - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dev.simcontactsmanager

Comment: Once you move to SIM you can delete from signed in accounts if that is your aim

Comment: @beeshyams thanks in my case I wanted to move between two different Google accounts . I'll give a shot to the application you mentioned

Comment: Moving between Google accounts - https://www.howtogeek.com/265006/how-to-transfer-contacts-between-google-accounts/

Comment: Login to both Google accounts at the same time and sync both. Then logout from the account you don't need anymore. I haven't tested it recently but it should work.

Comment: @IrfanLatif thanks I don't want to sync all contacts, but just move one contact

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt right. Then a simple approach can be to directly save to web UI

Comment: @IrfanLatif thanks what do you mean by save to web UI?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt login to Google account on a web browser and create a new contact.